# Weblogic class loading problem with shared JPA entities and Entity Manager

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, classloader, ejb-3.0

**What I want to do**

Let's say I have 3 modules: A, B and C. In module A I want to have JPA entities, DAOs and services used by both B and C.

Modules B and C are EJBs which expose SOAP web services. Both services are packaged in their own EARs, let's call them B_EAR and C_EAR.

Both EARs are deployed in the same Weblogic.

**Module overview**

```sh
A-- (this is an ejb-jar)
  |-src/pkg-entities/FooEntity.java
  |-src/pkg-dao/FooDAO.java
  |-src/pkg-services/FooService.java
  |-src/em/EntityManagerProducer.java
  |-resources/META-INF/beans.xml
  |-resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
B_EAR
  |-pom.xml (has as an ejb dependency the module B)
B-- (this is an EJB)
  |-src/pkg-name/SomeWebService.java
  |-resources/META-INF/ejb-ear.xml
  |-resources/META-INF/beans.xml
  |-resources/META-INF/weblogic-webservices.xml
  |-resources/META-INF/weblogic-webservices-policy.xml
  |-resources/META-INF/webservices.xml
  |-pom.xml (which includes as a dependency the module A)
C_EAR -> Similar to B_EAR
C -> Similar to B
```

The class `EntityManagerProducer.java` looks like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "foo")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Produces
  @FooQualifier
  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
  }
}
```

**Problem description**

If each EAR is deployed alone to Weblogic it works as expected. In case they are deployed together there are the following 2 class-loading issues:

1. The `FooEntity` is not recognized by the entity manager as entity. The error hints to check if there is a persistence.xml or if the `@Entity` annotation is missing. What is happening is that the `EntityManagerProducer` of module B returns an entity manager loaded by the class loader of module C which contains all the entities loaded by the class loader of C.
2. The other problem is that there are cases where a list of `FooEntity` objects may be returned and a `ClassCastException` is thrown when a class cast is going to be performed (for example a class cast happens implicitly when `list.stream()` is called).

The class loader of the module `C` is not parent to the one of `B`. They have both a common class loader parent (the common parent is the application class loader, the one after the system class loader).

The deployment order is significant and the error may not occur the same way if the initialization order of the entity manager changes.

**Some workarounds**

My current understanding is that each individual EAR (B_EAR and C_EAR) should have a separate class loader. It is not clear to me why this happens. Both class loaders are at the shame level in the hierarchy! ***Why is this happening?***

From what I have tried so far the only solution which worked was to deploy the module A under `domain/lib`. That way the entities were loaded in the system class-loader and were the same in all cases, so no class cast issues occurred. This approach is not the desired because it is hard to maintain.

Other than that I have tried the following without much success:

- Deploy module A as a Weblogic shared library. I was hoping to make the entities available to some class loader higher up in the hierarchy but this didn't worked like that.
- Change the persistence unit name to "foo-b" for module B and "foo-c" for module C (by changing the module A dependency individually). This didn't seem to work too.
- I was thinking to move the `persistence.xml` and `EntityManagerProducer` to modules `B` and `C` and use different persistence unit names. I think that this isn't possible but I am still looking into it.
- I think that deploying modules `B` and `C` into the same EAR would work because the same class loader should be used in all cases but this is not acceptable. It is a requirement the web services of module `B` and `C` to have different lifecycles.
- I have tried to set explicit class loading rules (with `prefer-application-packages` and `classloader-structure`) but without any success.

I hope to explained the issue well enough. Unfortunately, I cannot share any actual code. This seems fairly simple. ***What I am missing?*** How may I package the modules so they are still two different EARs deployed which share the same Entities and business code and avoid having all these issues?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try adding JPA provider classes within the Ear itself, and specifying that provider in the persistence.xml. Might be a long shot, but if it works, my guess is that the container is seeing these resources all use the same persistence unit and delegating to a provider it has loaded at the container class loader level, which is then reusing the first it loaded for all requests.  Logging might also help determine when the JPA deployment for these ears is happening and why it might have class loader problems.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for the recommendation. I didn't have time to explore this approach further yet. I'll get back to you when I have more news. Happy holidays!